# Factor: $x^3-4x^2-11x-6$

Tags: factoring

Factor: $$x^3-4x^2-11x-6$$
The answer is $(x-6)(x+1)^2$ but how do I get to it?
I tried many different methods but did not solve it correctly. Pleade help?

Comment: Did you try looking for obvious roots?  If you plug $-1$ in it's zero.  Once you know that you know $(x-1)$ is a factor.

Comment: @Gregory you mean $(x+1)$

Comment: Yeah at the equation it is obvious that 1 ,4 ,11, and 6 go together to give 0 if you have right signs. Then once you divide that out you have a quadratic and there's a known algorithm for checking quadratics for roots.

Comment: Yes sorry I meant $x+1$

Comment: Guess and Check!

Comment: If $f(x) = a_0x^n + a_1x^{n-1} + \cdots + a_n$, then $f(1) = a_0+a_1+\cdots + a_n$ and $f(-1) = a_0 -a_1+a_2 - \cdots $ or $-a_0+a_1-a_2+\cdots $ according as $n$ is even or odd. By remainder theorem, if $f(1) = 0$, $x-1$ is a factor and if $f(-1)=0$, $x+1$ is a factor. Stated otherwise, if the sum of all coefficients is zero, $x=1$ is a root and if alternate sum of coefficients is zero, $x=-1$ is a root. In this case, $1-(-4)+(-11)-(-6) = 0$ and hence $-1$ is a root.

Answer (score 2):

It's enough to find three roots, cause $w(a) = 0$ means that exists some polynomial $q(x)$, that $w(x) = (x-a)q(x)$. And your polynomial degree is 3.

You can check $0, 1, -1$ first. It's the easiest to do and in tasks often works. After that you needs something stronger:

Hint: [Rational root theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem) and not necessarily in this case [Horner's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horner%27s_method) to receive polynomial with degree two.

---

Comment: The rational root theorem say to check the divisors of the constant term; $0$ is not one of them, unless the constant term is $0$.

Comment: Oh, I think I see what you mean. Yes, 0 isn't from rational root theorem. If it's confusing, I will change my answer.

Comment: It's not really important. It was just for the sake of rigour, or my fussy side ;o)

Answer (score 1):

By the [rational root theorem](http://www.sparknotes.com/math/algebra2/polynomials/section4.rhtml), we guess the factors include at least one of the following:

$$x-6$$

$$x+6$$

$$x-2$$

$$x+2$$

$$x-3$$

$$x+3$$

$$x-1$$

$$x+1$$

Where did I get those?

1. Take the absolute value of the last term (in descending order), $6$, and the absolute value of the last term, $1$.
2. Take the factors of each:

$$6: \color{red}{1,2,3}$$

$$1: \color{green}{1}$$

3. Consider $x-a$ where $a$ may be any of the ff:

$$+\frac{\color{red}{6}}{\color{green}{1}}$$

$$-\frac{\color{red}{6}}{\color{green}{1}}$$

$$+\frac{\color{red}{3}}{\color{green}{1}}$$

$$-\frac{\color{red}{3}}{\color{green}{1}}$$

$$+\frac{\color{red}{2}}{\color{green}{1}}$$

$$-\frac{\color{red}{2}}{\color{green}{1}}$$

$$+\frac{\color{red}{1}}{\color{green}{1}}$$

$$-\frac{\color{red}{1}}{\color{green}{1}}$$